# shell script , space between word is working like enter

Tags: shell

i want output like

MADHYA PRADESH |740|Account Open
but i am getting it like
MADHYA
PRADESH|740|Account
Open

i wrote script for this

```
enter code here

 cd /home/XXXXX/
 USER_NAME=1234
 USER_PWD=1234
 DEBUG=0
```

clear

```
echo -e "\n Enter The From Date in specified format like DD-MON-YY \n "
read From_Date

echo -e "\n Enter The To Date in specified format like DD-MON-YY \n "
read To_Date


res=`sqlplus -S -L $USER_NAME/$USER_PWD<<EOF | tail -n +2
set pages 0
set linesize 1000
select sm.state_name||'|'||ua.phone||'|'||cm.err_message from tablename sm,tablename ua,tablename           cm where sm.s_id=ua.u_id and cm.c_id=ua.u_id and trunc(cm.date_created)>='$From_Date' and   trunc(cm.date_created)<='$To_Date';

EOF`

for d in $res;
do
echo $d
done
```

output for this is
   MADHYA 
   PRADESH|740|ACCOUNT
   OPEN

I want output like
   MADHYA PRADESH|740|ACCOUNT OPEN

Comment: I dont understand what you get is exactly what you wanted. Can you explain what problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this block:

```
for d in $res;
do
echo $d
done
```

And just use:

```
echo "$res"
```

There is no need to use `for` loop to print an already formatted string.